# Dataframe TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I do not understand why I get type error on this line:
new_jurnal_data = pd.DataFrame(jurnal_input_list, columns=sales_jurnal_columns)

Will apppreciate any feedbacks. Thank you so much.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mekar mulia\MM_penjualan_toped\2021_09_31 mm_penjualan_toped\MM_penjualan_20210930\main.py", line 465, in <module>
    new_jurnal_data = pd.DataFrame(jurnal_input_list, columns=sales_jurnal_columns)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 693, in __init__
    columns = ensure_index(columns)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6337, in ensure_index
    return Index(index_like, copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 494, in __new__
    subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=np.dtype("object"))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 227, in asarray_tuplesafe
    values = list(values)
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

This is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

# TAKE DATA FROM
wb_jurnal_product = load_workbook("MEKAR_MULIA_2_ProductExport_30_09_2021.xlsx")
ws_jurnal_product = wb_jurnal_product['30-09-2021']
jurnal_products_data = ws_jurnal_product.values
jurnal_product_columns = next(jurnal_products_data)[0:]
jurnal_product_df = pd.DataFrame(jurnal_products_data, columns=jurnal_product_columns)

jurnal_product_list = [i for i in jurnal_product_df['Name*']]
jurnal_unit_list = [i for i in jurnal_product_df['*Unit']]
jurnal_enumerated_product_list_object = enumerate(jurnal_product_list)
jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_tuple = [i for i in jurnal_enumerated_product_list_object]
jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_list = [list(i) for i in jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_tuple]
for x, y in zip(jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_list, jurnal_unit_list):
    x.append(y)
print(jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_list)


# ---------------------------------TOKOPEDIA SALES DATA----------------------------------------------------------------#

tokopedia_sales_xlsx = pd.ExcelFile("Tokopedia_Order_20210924-20210930 (1).xlsx")
tokopedia_sales_data = tokopedia_sales_xlsx.parse('Sheet1', skiprows=3, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])

# TODO: CORRECT TOKOPEDIA SALES DATA HEADER
# Prepare to correct the tokopedia header in the format of {'Order ID': 'Order_ID'}, to input inside columns keyword
tokopedia_sales_headers_list_before = list(tokopedia_sales_data.columns)
tokopedia_sales_headers_list_remove_underscore = [i.replace(" ", "_") for i in tokopedia_sales_data.columns]
tokopedia_sales_headers_list_remove_Rp = [i.replace("(Rp.)", "") for i in tokopedia_sales_headers_list_remove_underscore]
tokopedia_sales_headers_list_remove_SKU = [i.replace("(SKU)", "") for i in tokopedia_sales_headers_list_remove_Rp]

tokopedia_sales_header_dict = {}
for i in range(len(tokopedia_sales_headers_list_before)):
    tokopedia_sales_header_dict[i] = {tokopedia_sales_headers_list_before[i]: tokopedia_sales_headers_list_remove_SKU[i]}

# Remove the key number from tokopedia header dictionary
tokopedia_sales_header_unenumerated = [v for k, v in tokopedia_sales_header_dict.items()]

# Reformat the tokopedia header dictionary
from collections import ChainMap

corrected_toped_sales_header = dict(ChainMap(*tokopedia_sales_header_unenumerated))

# Reverse the order to correct the order of the header
toped_sales_header_reversed = {}
for k, v in corrected_toped_sales_header.items():
    dict_element = {k: v}
    dict_element.update(toped_sales_header_reversed)
    toped_sales_header_reversed = dict_element


# Rename the header
tokopedia_sales_data.rename(columns=toped_sales_header_reversed, inplace=True)


tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format = list(tokopedia_sales_data.Product_Name)

for x, y in enumerate(tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format):
    if y == 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 1 KG - KUNING':
        tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format[x] = jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_tuple[93][1]
    elif y == 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR) - Coklat, 5 pcs':
        tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format[x] = jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_tuple[41][1]
    elif y == 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR) - Vanila, 5 pcs':
        tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format[x] = jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_tuple[42][1]


tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_JURNAL_format = tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format
tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged = list(tokopedia_sales_data.Product_Name)

toped_sales_unit_raw = ['HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 1 KG - DUS', 'DANCOW FORTIGRO INSTANT COKLAT SUSU BUBUK 40GR', 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR)', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMIX INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500GR - DUS', 'MISTER POTATO CRISPS SAMBAL MATAH 85 GR - KERIPIK KENTANG', 'HAVERJOY INSTAN OAT 1 KG - DUS', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMIX INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 1 KG - DUS', 'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50ML', 'LAP SERAT SINTETIS FORTUNE - PCS', 'TONGKAT E TOL', 'WAFER LOACKER NAPOLITANER 175 GR', 'KITKAT MULTIPACK 2F ISI 6 PCS', 'TISSUE BASAH DETOL WET WIPES SENSITIVE ISI 10s', 'TISSUE BASAH DETOL WET WIPES ISI 50 LEMBAR', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AAA / A3 ISI 6 PCS', 'HAVERJOY QUICK COOKING OATS 1KG - DUS', 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 1 KG - DUS', 'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50ML', 'KONDOM SUTRA OK ISI 12 PCS', 'KONDOM FIESTA BUBBLE GUM ISI 3 PCS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AAA / A3 ISI 6 PCS', 'OREO FIZZY 123,5 GR', 'PALMOLIVE SHAMPOO INTENSIVE MOISTURE COCO DREAM & MILK PROTEIN 350 ML', 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 1 KG - DUS', 'OATSY STEEL CUT OATS 750 GR', 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 500GR - DUS', 'MISTER POTATO CRISPS BALADO 85 GR - KERIPIK KENTANG', 'MISTER POTATO CRISPS HONEY CHEESE 85 GR - KERIPIK KENTANG', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AAA / A3 ISI 6 PCS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'LUWAK WHITE KOFFIE LESS SUGAR ISI 20 SACHET', 'BOLDE SUPER MOP ALAT PEL BISON', 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 500GR - DUS', 'MISTER POTATO CRISPS SAMBAL MATAH 85 GR - KERIPIK KENTANG', 'FRISIAN FLAG PUREFARM FULL CREAM 800 GR', 'MINUMAN YEOS CHRYSANTHEMUM 250 ML', 'HAVERJOY INSTAN OAT 500GR - DUS', 'QUAKER SPECIAL PACKAGE INSTAN OATMEAL 800 GR', 'BISKUIT MARIE REGAL 230GR', 'KUNCI PENGAMAN KULKAS', 'FRISIAN FLAG PUREFARM FULL CREAM 800 GR', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'HAVERJOY INSTAN OAT 500GR - DUS', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMIX INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500GR - DUS', 'SUSU VIDORAN XMART 5+MADU 725 GR', 'HAVERJOY INSTAN OAT 1 KG - DUS', 'Palmolive Natural Ultra Smooth Aloe Vera Shampoo & Conditioner 350 ML', 'SIRUP ABC SPECIAL MELON 485ML - PCS', 'MISTER POTATO CRISPS SAMBAL MATAH 85 GR - KERIPIK KENTANG', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AAA / A3 ISI 6 PCS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 24 PCS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AAA / A3 ISI 6 PCS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'KUNCI PENGAMAN KULKAS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AAA / A3 ISI 6 PCS', 'QUAKER SPECIAL PACKAGE INSTAN OATMEAL 800 GR', 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR)', 'HIT LILY BLOSSOM 600 ML + 75 ML', 'SO GOOD ANIMAL 400 GR', 'HAVERJOY INSTAN OAT 1 KG - DUS', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMIX INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 1 KG - DUS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AAA / A3 ISI 6 PCS', 'ROSE BRAND TEBU GULA PASIR 1 KG', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AAA / A3 ISI 6 PCS', 'LIFEBUOY BODY WASH 900 ML REFILL', 'PIPO MINNIE SEMI GEL 0,5MM BLACK', 'PIPO GOOFY SEMI GEL 0,5MM BLACK', 'PIPO DONALD SEMI GEL PEN 0,5MM BLACK', 'PIPO MICKEY SEMI GEL PEN 0,5MM BLACK', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMIX INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500GR - DUS', 'HAVERJOY QUICK COOKING OATS 500GR - DUS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'Palmolive Natural Ultra Smooth Aloe Vera Shampoo & Conditioner 350 ML', 'ENEMA UK 89 ML BLACK', 'QUAKER FESTIVE INSTANT OATMEAL 800 GR', 'FRISIAN FLAG PUREFARM FULL CREAM 800 GR', 'Palmolive Natural Ultra Smooth Aloe Vera Shampoo & Conditioner 350 ML', 'KONDOM SUTRA GERIGI ISI 3 PCS', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 24 PCS', 'BAWANG PUTIH', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 24 PCS', 'LAP SERAT SINTETIS FORTUNE - PCS', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 24 PCS', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50ML', 'MISTER POTATO CRISPS HONEY CHEESE 85 GR - KERIPIK KENTANG', 'Spons Pembersih Kerak Panci Spon Nano Magic Penghilang Kerak dan Noda', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'HANNOCHS NEX LAMPU LED PUTIH 12 WATT', 'BOLDE SUPER MOP ALAT PEL BISON', 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 1 KG - DUS', 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 1 KG - DUS', 'BUAH LECI DALAM KALENG/ HERRING BRAND CANNED LYCHEES IN SYRUP 567 GR', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'SUTRA TISU PLUS ISI 3 SHEET', 'SUTRA LUBRICANT 50 ML', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 24 PCS', 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR)', 'BAWANG PUTIH', 'QUAKER SPECIAL PACKAGE INSTAN OATMEAL 800 GR', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMIX INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500GR - DUS', 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 500GR - DUS', 'PIPO  MICKEY KING JELLER GEL PEN 0,5MM BLUE', 'PIPO  MICKEY KING JELLER GEL PEN 0,5MM BLACK', 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 500GR - DUS', 'HAVERJOY INSTAN OAT 500GR - DUS', 'KERTAS KADO KECIL', 'BATERAI ALKALINE AA / A2 ISI 6 PCS', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMIX INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500GR - DUS', 'HAVERJOY INSTAN OAT 1 KG - DUS', 'FRISIAN FLAG PUREFARM FULL CREAM 800 GR', 'KONDOM FIESTA DELAY ISI 3 PCS', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMIX INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 1 KG - DUS']
for x, y in enumerate(toped_sales_unit_raw):
    if y == 'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 1 KG - DUS':
        toped_sales_unit_raw[x] = jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_list[93][2]
    elif y == 'DANCOW FORTIGRO INSTANT COKLAT SUSU BUBUK 40GR':
        toped_sales_unit_raw[x] = jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_list[41][2]
    elif y == 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR)':
        toped_sales_unit_raw[x] = jurnal_enumerated_product_list_of_list[42][2]
    
# IMPLEMENT DATA TO CSV
tokopedia_sales_empty_data = ['' for i in range(len(tokopedia_sales_data))]
tokopedia_sales_customer = list(tokopedia_sales_data.Customer_Name)
tokopedia_sales_email = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_billing_addr = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_shipping_addr = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_invoice_date = [i.split(' ')[0] for i in list(tokopedia_sales_data.Payment_Date)]
tokopedia_sales_due_date = tokopedia_sales_invoice_date
tokopedia_sales_shipping_date = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_ship_via = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_tracking_no = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_cust_ref_no = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_invoice_no = list(tokopedia_sales_data.Invoice)
tokopedia_sales_message = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_product_name = tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_JURNAL_format
tokopedia_sales_desc = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_qty = list(tokopedia_sales_data.Quantity)
tokopedia_sales_unit = toped_sales_unit_raw
tokopedia_sales_unit_price = list(tokopedia_sales_data.Price_)
tokopedia_sales_product_disc = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_invoice_disc = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_tax_name = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_tax_rate = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_shipping_fee = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_witholding_acc = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_witholding_amt = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_paid_status = ['no' for i in range(len(tokopedia_sales_data))]
tokopedia_sales_payment_method = ['Bank Transfer' for i in range(len(tokopedia_sales_data))]
tokopedia_sales_paid_to_account_code = ['1-10002' for i in range(len(tokopedia_sales_data))]
tokopedia_sales_tags = tokopedia_sales_empty_data
tokopedia_sales_warehouse_name = ['GUDANG RIAU' for i in range(len(tokopedia_sales_data))]
tokopedia_sales_currency = ['IDR' for i in range(len(tokopedia_sales_data))]


tokopedia_sales_bebas_ongkir = list(tokopedia_sales_data.Bebas_Ongkir)
tokopedia_sales_memo = ['HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 1 KG - KUNING', 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR) - Coklat, 5 pcs', 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR) - Vanila, 5 pcs', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500 GR', 'KERIPIK KENTANG - MISTER POTATO CRISPS 85 GR - RASA SAMBAL MATAH', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS 1 KG - MERAH', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 1 KG', 'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50 ML', 'LAP Kanebo FortuneR Serat 43X32mm Tebal 2mm JAPAN QUALITY', 'Tongkat etoll tongtol kartu parkir e-toll gerbang tol', 'WAFER - LOACKER NAPOLITANER 175 GR - WAFER DENGAN KRIM KACANG HAZEL', 'KitKat Multipack 2F isi 6pcs / Cokelat', 'DETTOL WET WIPES SENSITIVE TISSUE BASAH ISI 10s', 'TISU BASAH / TISSUE BASAH DETOL WET WIPES ISI 50 LEMBAR', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AAA / A3 isi 6 pcs original', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT QUICK COOKING OATS 1 KG - KEMASAN COKLAT', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 1 KG - KUNING', 'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50 ML', 'Kondom Sutra Ok isi 1 / 3 / 12 / 24 bukan durex / fiesta - 12pcs', 'Kondom Bubble Gum Isi 3 pcs - Alat Kontrasepsi', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AAA / A3 isi 6 pcs original', 'OREO FIZZY ORANGE 123,5 GR', 'PALMOLIVE Shampoo Intensive Moisture Coco Dream & Milk Protein 350ml', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 1 KG - KUNING', 'OATSY STEEL CUT OATS OAT 750 GR bukan quaker haverjoy', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 500 GR - KUNING', 'KERIPIK KENTANG - MISTER POTATO CRIPS 85 GR - RASA BALADO', 'Mister Potato HONEY CHEESE 85 GR (KEJU MADU) - Keripik kentang', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AAA / A3 isi 6 pcs original', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'KOPI KEMASAN - LUWAK WHITE KOFFIE LESS SUGAR ISI 20 SACHET', 'BOLDE SUPER MOP ALAT PEL BISON - BIRU TOSCA', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 500 GR - KUNING', 'KERIPIK KENTANG - MISTER POTATO CRISPS 85 GR - RASA SAMBAL MATAH', 'SUSU BUBUK - FRISIAN FLAG PUREFARM FULL CREAM 800 GR', 'MINUMAN - YEOS CHRYSANTHEMUM 250 ML - RASA BUNGA KRISANTEMUM', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTAN OAT 500 GR - MERAH', 'Quaker Festive Instant Oatmeal 800 Gr - FREE Bowl and Scoop', 'Regal Biskuit Marie Special 230 GR biscuit', 'Kunci Pengaman Jendela Kulkas Bahan Stainless Steel', 'SUSU BUBUK - FRISIAN FLAG PUREFARM FULL CREAM 800 GR', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTAN OAT 500 GR - MERAH', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500 GR', 'SUSU VIDORAN XMART 5+ MADU BOX 725 GR', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS 1 KG - MERAH', 'Palmolive Natural Ultra Smooth Aloe Vera Shampoo & Conditioner 350 ML', 'Sirup ABC Melon Special Grade - 485ml', 'KERIPIK KENTANG - MISTER POTATO CRISPS 85 GR - RASA SAMBAL MATAH', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AAA / A3 isi 6 pcs original', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 1 3 12 24 SUTERA MERAH not durex / fiesta - 3pcs', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AAA / A3 isi 6 pcs original', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'Kunci Pengaman Jendela Kulkas Bahan Stainless Steel', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AAA / A3 isi 6 pcs original', 'Quaker Festive Instant Oatmeal 800 Gr - FREE Bowl and Scoop', 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR) - Vanila, 10pcs', 'HIT AEROSOL ORANGE 600 ML + 75 ML - LILY BLOSSOM', 'MAKANAN BEKU - NUGGET - S GOOD CHICKEN NUGGET ANIMAL / ALPHABET 400 GR - alphabet', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS 1 KG - MERAH', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 1 KG', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AAA / A3 isi 6 pcs original', 'ROSE BRAND TEBU GULA PASIR 1 KG', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AAA / A3 isi 6 pcs original', 'LIFEBUOY BODY WASH 900 ML REFILL', 'PIPO MINNIE SEMI GEL PEN 0.5 MM BLACK - 1 pcs', 'PIPO GOOFY SEMI GEL PEN 0.5 MM BLACK - 1 pcs', 'PIPO DONALD SEMI GEL PEN 0.5 MM BLACK - 1 pcs', 'PIPO MICKEY SEMI GEL PEN 0.5 MM BLACK - 1 pcs', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500 GR', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT QUICK COOKING OATS 500GR - KEMASAN COKLAT', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'Palmolive Natural Ultra Smooth Aloe Vera Shampoo & Conditioner 350 ML', 'ENEMA ANAL CLEANER SMALL / ALAT PEMBERSIH ANUS 89 ML -100% ORI - Hitam', 'QUAKER INSTAN OATMEAL 800 GR FREE QUAKER FOOD STORAGE', 'SUSU BUBUK - FRISIAN FLAG PUREFARM FULL CREAM 800 GR', 'Palmolive Natural Ultra Smooth Aloe Vera Shampoo & Conditioner 350 ML', 'Alat Kontrasepsi Kondom Sutra Gerigi isi 1 / 3 / 12 not durex / fiesta - 3pcs', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 1 3 12 24 SUTERA MERAH not durex / fiesta - 24pcs', 'Bawang Putih Kating Kupas / Utuh - 250 gr, Utuh', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 1 3 12 24 SUTERA MERAH not durex / fiesta - 24pcs', 'LAP Kanebo FortuneR Serat 43X32mm Tebal 2mm JAPAN QUALITY', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 1 3 12 24 SUTERA MERAH not durex / fiesta - 24pcs', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50 ML', 'Mister Potato HONEY CHEESE 85 GR (KEJU MADU) - Keripik kentang', 'Spons Pembersih Kerak Panci Spon Nano Magic Penghilang Kerak dan Noda', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'LAMPU - BOHLAM - HANNOCHS NEX LAMPU LED - PUTIH 12 WATT', 'BOLDE SUPER MOP ALAT PEL BISON - BIRU TOSCA', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 1 KG - KUNING', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 1 KG - KUNING', 'BUAH LECI DALAM KALENG/ HERRING BRAND CANNED LYCHEES IN SYRUP 567 GR', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'Sutra Tisu Plus Isi 3 Sachet', 'Produk Dewasac - Sutra Lubricant 50 ml Pelumas / Pelicin / Lubrikan', 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 1 3 12 24 SUTERA MERAH not durex / fiesta - 24pcs', 'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR) - Vanila, 1 pcs', 'Bawang Putih Kating Kupas / Utuh - 100 gr, Utuh', 'Quaker Festive Instant Oatmeal 800 Gr - FREE Bowl and Scoop', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500 GR', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 500 GR - KUNING', 'PIPO MICKEY KING JELLER GEL PEN 0.5 MM - Biru, 1 pcs', 'PIPO MICKEY KING JELLER GEL PEN 0.5 MM - Hitam, 1 pcs', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 500 GR - KUNING', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTAN OAT 500 GR - MERAH', 'ECER Kertas Kado / Bungkus Kado SANSAN WAWA', 'Battery / Baterai Alkaline AA / A2 isi 6 pcs original - 6 pcs', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 500 GR', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS 1 KG - MERAH', 'SUSU BUBUK - FRISIAN FLAG PUREFARM FULL CREAM 800 GR', 'Kondom Fiesta Delay Isi 3 pcs', 'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT INSTANT OATS & CHOCO CHIPS 1 KG']

for x in range(len(tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged)):
    if tokopedia_sales_bebas_ongkir[x] == "Yes":
        tokopedia_sales_memo[x] = "potongan bebas ongkir dan power merchant 3%"
    else:
        tokopedia_sales_memo[x] = "potongan power merchant pro 1.5%"

for x in range(len(tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged)):
    if tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged[x] == 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 1 3 12 24 SUTERA MERAH not durex / fiesta - 3pcs':
        if tokopedia_sales_bebas_ongkir[x] == "Yes":
            tokopedia_sales_qty[x] = tokopedia_sales_qty[x] * 3 / 24
            tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] = tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] * 8 * (1 - 0.03)
        else:
            tokopedia_sales_qty[x] = tokopedia_sales_qty[x] * 3 / 24
            tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] = tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] * 8 * (1 - 0.015)
    elif tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged[x] == 'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 1 3 12 24 SUTERA MERAH not durex / fiesta - 1pcs':
        if tokopedia_sales_bebas_ongkir[x] == "Yes":
            tokopedia_sales_qty[x] = tokopedia_sales_qty[x] * 1 / 24
            tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] = tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] * 24 * (1 - 0.03)
        else:
            tokopedia_sales_qty[x] = tokopedia_sales_qty[x] * 1 / 24
            tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] = tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] * 24 * (1 - 0.015)
    elif tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged[x] == 'PIPO MINNIE SEMI GEL PEN 0.5 MM BLACK - 1 pcs' or \
            tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged[x] == 'PIPO GOOFY SEMI GEL PEN 0.5 MM BLACK - 1 pcs' or \
            tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged[x] == 'PIPO DONALD SEMI GEL PEN 0.5 MM BLACK - 1 pcs' or \
            tokopedia_sales_product_name_in_toped_format_unchanged[x] == 'PIPO MICKEY SEMI GEL PEN 0.5 MM BLACK - 1 pcs':
        if tokopedia_sales_bebas_ongkir[x] == "Yes":
            tokopedia_sales_qty[x] = tokopedia_sales_qty[x] * 1 / 12
            tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] = tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] * 12 * (1 - 0.03)
        else:
            tokopedia_sales_qty[x] = tokopedia_sales_qty[x] * 1 / 12
            tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] = tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] * 12 * (1 - 0.015)
    else:
        if tokopedia_sales_bebas_ongkir[x] == "Yes":
            tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] = tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] * (1 - 0.03)
        else:
            tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] = tokopedia_sales_unit_price[x] * (1 - 0.015)

jurnal_input_list = []
for i in range(len(tokopedia_sales_customer)):
    jurnal_input_list.append([tokopedia_sales_customer[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_email[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_billing_addr[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_shipping_addr[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_invoice_date[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_due_date[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_shipping_date[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_ship_via[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_tracking_no[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_cust_ref_no[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_invoice_no[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_message[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_memo[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_product_name[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_desc[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_qty[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_unit[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_unit_price[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_product_disc[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_invoice_disc[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_tax_name[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_tax_rate[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_shipping_fee[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_witholding_acc[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_witholding_amt[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_paid_status[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_payment_method[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_paid_to_account_code[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_tags[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_warehouse_name[i],
                 tokopedia_sales_currency[i]])

sales_jurnal_data = pd.read_csv("SalesInvoiceImportTemplateMC.csv")
sales_jurnal_columns = sales_jurnal_data.head

new_jurnal_data = pd.DataFrame(jurnal_input_list, columns=sales_jurnal_columns)
new_jurnal_data.to_csv("SalesInvoiceInputTemplate_20210924-20210930.csv")
```

Comment: To get the head, call the method: `sales_jurnal_columns = sales_jurnal_data.head()`

Comment: I tried it, but I got this instead of a list: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [*Customer, Email, BillingAddress, ShippingAddress, *InvoiceDate, *DueDate, ShippingDate, ShipVia, TrackingNo, CustomerRefNo, *InvoiceNumber, Message, Memo, *ProductName, Description, *Quantity, Unit, *UnitPrice, ProductDiscountRate(%), InvoiceDiscountRate(%), TaxName, TaxRate(%), ShippingFee, WitholdingAccountCode, WitholdingAmount(value or %), #paid?(yes/no), #PaymentMethod, #PaidToAccountCode, Tags (use ; to separate tags), WarehouseName, #currency code(example: IDR, USD, CAD)]
Index: []

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame` expects a numpy array. `jurnal_input_list` is list, not a numpy array. You can try to convert the `jurnal_input_list` to numpy array first as follows:

```
new_jurnal_data = pd.DataFrame(numpy.array(jurnal_input_list), columns=sales_jurnal_columns)
```

Comment: I tried yours, but then I got a name error: NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined

Comment: `import numpy` or `import numpy as np`

Comment: successfully install numpy, then I get ValueError: Shape of passed values is (116, 31), indices imply (116, 0)

Comment: is there anything I can try to fix this?

Comment: @Stephen Can you put numpy.array([jurnal_input_list]) instead of numpy.array(jurnal_input_list) and check?